# How to simplify big CASE-statement?

Tags: t-sql

I would like to make this properly working code a bit more...beautiful.

```
SET @weightClass = CASE 
    WHEN @totalWeight < 50 THEN 'A'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 100 THEN 'B'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 150 THEN 'C'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 200 THEN 'D'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 250 THEN 'E'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 300 THEN 'F'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 350 THEN 'G'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 400 THEN 'H'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 450 THEN 'I'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 500 THEN 'J'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 550 THEN 'K'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 600 THEN 'L'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 650 THEN 'M'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 700 THEN 'N'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 750 THEN 'O'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 800 THEN 'P'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 850 THEN 'Q'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 900 THEN 'R'
    WHEN @totalWeight < 950 THEN 'S'
    ELSE 'T'
END
```

I'm thinking that there might be a way to use the ASCII-value of the letters and the logical increment of 50. Would it be possible (and feasible) to make this? How and would it slow down the query noticeably?

Comment: possible while loop? and since the increments are in an alphabetic order it shouldn't be too hard to make it work.

Comment: Define a weightClass table, possibly with exclusive weight ranges, join on a between condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function to get a character is CHAR()
The ascii code for A is 65

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN @totalWeight >= 950 THEN 'T'
    ELSE CHAR(@totalWeight / 50 + 65)
END
```

Comment: How would I cap it off at 'T'?

Comment: I think it should be +65. When I run with the value 49 otherwise I get '@'. Edit: Like this: SELECT CHAR((@totalWeight / 50) + 65)

Comment: @Danieboy - I think you're right! It's rounding down to 0 (int division). My bad. Fixed that and updated to respect maxing out at 'T'

Comment: @Danieboy - Having tested it (albeit using MySQL and FLOOR-ing the float division), I think the first version was actually correct (49/50 => 0, 50/50 => 1), so I've removed the erroneous second answer.